# lxml: modified escaping scheme

Tags: python, lxml

For our application, we'd like quotes (both single and double) to be quoted, but there's no need to quote the shy character.

To make this more concrete, this code:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring, tostring
parsed = fromstring(u'<div>That fire&shy;fighter is 6&#39;11&#34; tall!</div>')
print repr(tostring(parsed, encoding=unicode))
```

... has this output:

```
u'<div>That fire\xadfighter is 6\'11" tall!</div>'
```

... but I want this output:

```
u'<div>That fire\xadfighter is 6&#39;11&#34; tall!</div>'
```

In essence, I want to override the default encoding / escaping behavior.

---

As far as I can tell, this isn't supported in libxml2. I'll accept a fully-reliable (and hopefully fast) post-processing method as well, for now.